# How can I configure Path for two services in Kubernetes Ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

I've the following ingress configuration but when I call `www.domain.com/api` it always open my UI service instead of API and the same thing happens if I call something else after **api**, for example `www.domain.com/api/v1/projects`.

How can I fix that?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: tls
  backend:
    serviceName: ui
    servicePort: 5003
  rules:
  - host: www.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: ui
          servicePort: 5003
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: api
          servicePort: 5000
```

Comment: How about to remove the default backend '  backend:
    serviceName: ui
    servicePort: 5003' . https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/#single-service-ingress . I think you will need the simple-fanout setup https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/#simple-fanout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way I fixed this problem. I hope this can help others.

Thanks @aleks!!

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kronus
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: tls
  backend:
    serviceName: ui
    servicePort: 5003
  rules:
  - host: domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: api
          servicePort: 5000
      - path: /api/*
        backend:
          serviceName: api
          servicePort: 5000
  - host: www.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: api
          servicePort: 5000
      - path: /api/*
        backend:
          serviceName: api
          servicePort: 5000
```

Comment: could you please click the tick on your answer to 'accept' it and people will know that the question is solved?

Comment: I need to wait 11h before I can accept my answer to close it.